# Locate the reasoning for NULL values between HTML and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to figure out why the resulting values are...

> NULL NULL string(4) "PEAR"

..on the page they are displayed on.
Originally I do not want them to be displayed but I want the php code to run, using local storage data, when the page loads, then possibly return a boolean value or something in that direction. With a set goal in mind, I am looking for the mistake I have made that creates the NULL values. I have the following code:

**validateSession.php** , php functionality that will validate values from localstorage and database

```
<?php
    include("config.php");
    include("refc/refcvalidation.php");
    $sesuserid = $_POST[$valuserid];
    $sessionid = $_POST[$valsesid];
    
    var_dump($sesuserid, $sessionid);
    
    $conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die($conn);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sessiontable WHERE sesowner=? AND sescode=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $sesuserid, $sessionid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $conn->close();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        var_dump("APPLES");
    }else{
        var_dump("PEAR");
    }
?>
```

**refcvalidation.php** , reference coordination, ensuring same value on both pages

```
<?php
    $valuserid = "VALSES1";
    $valsesid = "VALSES2";
?>
```

**homepage.php** , basic page with contents

```
<?php
    include("services/refc/refcvalidation.php");
    include('services/validateSession.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general/styling.css">
    <script src="general/launch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="topBox">

</div>
<div class="box">
    <form id="logForm" action="validateSession.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" required="required" name="<?php echo $valuserid ?>" id="userfield">
        <input type="hidden" required="required" name="<?php echo $valsesid ?>" id="sesidfield">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<style>
</style>
</html>
<script>
    document.getElementById("userfield").value = localStorage.getItem("userid");
    document.getElementById("sesidfield").value = localStorage.getItem("sessionid");
</script>
```

The values within HTML are set and have a value in the script section, they are null within the PHP $_POST[$valuserid]; and $_POST[$valsesid]; . Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you use `$_POST[$valuserid]` to get the user ID? What does `$valuserid` contain?

Comment: That is because of the name from the input fields in HTML, they are refered to with the same name as they are given in HTML. For them to know whcih values to use they need to have the same name as the ones in HTML input fields.

Comment: This would be just the same if you hardcoded the field names.  It seems as though you are over-complicating things. (IMHO)

Comment: Well the way I look at it.. If I ever need them changed I can change 2 fields in 1 file, instead of 4 fields in 2 files. :-) But you are correct with the hardcoding. I just prefer to make it esier to develop and change if needed.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Can you dump `$_POST` to see what it contains?

Comment: As shown in the code snippet 1, **validateSession.php**, they are NULL.

Comment: Where do you dump `$_POST` in that snippet? As far as I see, you do not dump that array, but only other variables

Comment: @NicoHaase AH, my mistake. I assumed you wanted the variables. The **$_POST** results in: **array(0) { }**

Comment: So, if the `$_POST` array is empty, you haven't sent any values using that form. Keep on debugging how the request is sent, for example through your browser's network console

Answer (score 0):

Have'nt tested this, but it might give you some ideas to a solution.

Maybe we could impolement some Ajax into this?

**What is Ajax?**

`AJAX = Asynchronous JavaScript and XML. AJAX is a technique for creating fast and dynamic web pages. AJAX allows web pages to be updated asynchronously by exchanging small amounts of data with the server behind the scenes. This means that it is possible to update parts of a web page, without reloading the whole page. Ajax can give data as response.`

**refcvalidation.php**

This should be removed

---

**validateSession.php**

```php
<?php
    include("config.php");
    //include("refc/refcvalidation.php"); //REMOVED
    $sesuserid = $_POST['valuserid'];
    $sessionid = $_POST['valsesid'];
    
    $conn = new mysqli($dbservername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname) or die($conn);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sessiontable WHERE sesowner=? AND sescode=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("is", $sesuserid, $sessionid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $conn->close();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $myObj->sesuserid = $sesuserid;
        $myObj->sessionid = $sessionid;

        $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);

        echo $myJSON;
        return true;  //CONTAINS SOMETHING
    }else{
        return false; //CONTAINS NOTHING
    }
?>
```

**homepage.php**

```php
<?php
    include("services/refc/refcvalidation.php");
    include('services/validateSession.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="general/styling.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="general/launch.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="topBox">

</div>
<div class="box">
    <form id="logForm" action="validateSession.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" required="required" name="<?php echo $valuserid ?>" id="userfield">
        <input type="hidden" required="required" name="<?php echo $valsesid ?>" id="sesidfield">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
<style>
</style>
</html>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: 'validateSession.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { valuserid: '<?php echo $valsesid ?>', valsesid: '<?php echo $valsesid ?>'},
        success: function(data) {
            var data_json= JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data_sjon);
            localStorage.userid = data_json[0];
            localStorage.sesidfield = data_json[1];
            document.getElementById("userfield").value = localStorage.getItem("userid");
            document.getElementById("sesidfield").value = localStorage.getItem("sessionid");
        }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have seen mentions of AJAX several times and have not yet jumped over to it, as I have not needed it before. I will give this set of code a try later today.